# Zend Framework 2 restrict route to controller action

Tags: zend-framework2

Have searched for this but i'm coming up short.
What is the best way to restrict access to an action in a controller in ZF2?
What i want is to only call a certain action in a controller (which is in a different module) if the request comes from a specific action - if not redirect to 404.
I see that i can use

```
$this->getRequest()->getUri()->getPath()
```

to get the current URL, but what i want is the previous one?
I could put this in a session variable, or pass it as a parameter in the route but is there a better way?
Reason is that i have a multi step form and i wish to only allow step 2 if the user came from step 1, otherwise 404.

What is the recommended ZF2 practice for this?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not handle this via urls. I'd look into Zend\Session\Container to manage state explicitly after you submit the first form.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I dont think i can use the Session as Step 1 generates a URL that is sent to the users email for them to click on. Once they click on this they are validated and brought to Step 2. I want to ensure that they cant just type the URL for Step 2 into the browser, that it is only ever called from the URL generated from Step 1.